# Should this site be combined with the Artificial Intelligence stack exchange?

Tags: discussion, community, ai-stack-exchange

According to my scope of the subjects. Artificial intelligence in a very strict sense should only contain questions pertaining to how we can create truly intelligent (creative, aware, etc.) machines. Whereas data science is directly the manipulation of data in order to produce tools to make something better (image detection, intrusion detection, etc.). The separation is very blurry and I do not think that intelligence can exist without information/data, and its manipulations. However, most machine learning and deep learning demonstrated are simply conducting complex function approximations.

However, due to the popularization of machine learning and especially deep learning, the manipulation of data has created the impression of intelligent machine due to it being capable of competing with human performance in very targeted tasks (object recognition, segmentation, etc.). Evidently, the name artificial intelligence catches people's attention much more than data science or machine learning. Thus, it is common for news which is essentially generic data science/machine learning to be called artificial intelligence.

This is further demonstrated on the Artificial Intelligence site where the majority of the questions are pertaining more to data science and machine learning than truly discussing possibilities, methods or emerging work pertaining to machines capable of intelligence.

Comment: You are not the first one with this opinion :D Honestly, I find the scope of the AI site still [very vague](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1099/101). They close off a lot of applied AI questions. So, not sure if this proposal would excite them

Comment: I can imagine that this idea would come with some resistance, but the fields are merging very quickly. I sometimes don't know which community I should ask in. Realistically, people just want their questions answered. Thus separating the community of potential people who can answer is not ideal.

Answer (score 7):

In practice most questions posted on the Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange are also very much on-topic on DS and Cross Validated. It makes no sense to have 3 different Stack Exchange websites for the same topic branded differently. My stance is that AI, DS and Cross Validated should be merged together.

On the same topic:

- [Are all questions asked on stats and data science SE also on topic here?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4/4)
- [After Data Science SE: Artificial Intelligence SE](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4243/12359)
- [CV and Data Science: semi-identical twins?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2253/12359)

Comment: Tags should sufficient to differentiate the three topic areas. There's no need for completely separate subdomains.

Answer (score 5):

I know nothing about how the mechanics of sites merging might actually work, but...

I presume that if that were a thing, it would require (somehow) the communities to agree on such a thing.  But, as pointed out in the answers to [dawny33's post](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1099/101) on AI's meta; This seems unlikely.  Stack Exchange AI (not unlike Data Science) thinks they have a niche and have struck out on their own to try and find it.

<sub>In many peoples mind, there still exists a question of whether or not Data Science should merge with [Stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).  The world goes round.</sub>

Comment: They may think they have a niche but in practice, looking at existing questions, they don't.

Comment: I actually see the need for separation between formal statistics and data science. The first is more theory, the second more applications. It's like math.SE versus... let's say engineering.SE as an arbitrary example.